# Python calling C++/CLI dll function using pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, .net, c++-cli, python.net

I've compiled a dll from a C++/CLI project in Visual Studio.

The code looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "api209.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace api209;

namespace CDK_net {

    public ref class CDK_wrapper
    {
   public:
      CDK_wrapper::CDK_wrapper(){};

   public:
      void init(){
         //some magic
      }
    };
}
```

So this dll references a few other native C++ dlls and libraries, and does some stuff in the `init()` function.

If I create a C# project, reference this dll, the `CDK_wrapper.init()` works perfectly fine.

Now I want to reference this dll from a python script. So I have Python 2.7.15 and pythonnet to allow me to do this.

If I create a simple script:

```
import sys
import clr

dlldir = "C:\\dir\\of\\dll\\"
dllname = "CDK_net"

sys.path.append(dlldir)

clr.AddReference(dllname)

from CDK_net import CDK_wrapper

cdk = CDK_wrapper()
#works fine until here
cdk.init()
```

I get the following error when running it in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 33, in <module>
    cdk.init()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at api209.model.open(model* , SByte* , Repository* )
   at CDK_net.CDK_wrapper.init() in d:\(...)cdk_net.h:line 21
```

So the error traces back to function in a C++ library which is referenced by my C++/CLI managed dll.

My question is; whatever is happening in the `init()` function in my dll, if it works when being called by a C# application, is there any reason why it shouldn't work when being called by python using pythonnet?

Comment: Can you catch the exception in C++/CLI to print whatever information it gives? Is there any information in that exception?

Comment: did you match the 32/64-bit architecture for python/c#/c++?